# Can we reopen this question about how to install Ubuntu on a 32 bit mac with 64 bit processor?

Tags: discussion

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466964/installing-ubuntu-linux-mint-on-macbook-1-1) question about installing Ubuntu on a 32-bit Mac.

It seems that [this Mac](https://igotoffer.com/apple/macbook-air-1-1) has a 64 bit processor, and Ubuntu should support it.

Since this question broadly falls in the range of "How to install Ubuntu on a particular platform?", it should be on-topic although it requires using MacOS to create a live media.

Comment: Guys, the goal of this site is to help people who want to use Ubuntu, and not to harass potentially new users.

Comment: Could you please suggest an edit to the question that removes the indication that the CPU is 32 bit?

Comment: Question was edited, and it's been reopened.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I must ask you honestly: what makes you think there's "harassment" going on of 'new users'?  This isn't *usually* the case here.

Comment: @ThomasWard There are a few users (I don't want to name anyone) who try to ask users clarification about whether they are using "Ubuntu Core 20", in case the user mentions "Ubuntu 20", although it is very evident whether the users are using the desktop version (expert users who might need core 20 would know what they are doing).

Comment: @ThomasWard Also, there is a trend to immediately close a question without reading it properly (e.g., this question was about installing Ubuntu, but the user does not have an existing Ubuntu computer, and wanted to use MacOS to make the live media), or trying to edit it to make it more suitable for this site.

Comment: @ThomasWard Often, valid questions like this are closed within minutes before the OP can respond back in the comments/make an edit. Once a question is forcefully closed before the new user can respond back, it would be very frustrating for them, as it takes a lot of time to reopen the question. This is what I meant new users being “harrassed”. Also, people usually ask question because they face a problem regarding Ubuntu, and they might simply go away from Ubuntu/Linux if they face such behavior from existing users.

Comment: @ThomasWard I feel that we need more strict rules about how the posts of new users should be treated. Most of them are not spam, and many of them are on-topic. I feel that we should ask them for clarification and wait, before casting a closed vote on the grounds of "needs more clarity" .

Comment: In this particular question which was reopened, it seems like OP left after the question was closed, and never came back

Comment: RE: First Comment: And that's a problem, why?  That's not being patronizing, because "Ubuntu 20" and 'Ubuntu 22" are in fact Core releases.  22.04 and 20.04 are not.

Comment: RE: Second and Third Comment: It's trivially easy to get things reopened once details are provided.  Just because reviewers use their close votes doesn't mean that's a blocker for posting because it can always be reopened once details are available.  Simply flagging a post for mod attention is sufficient to get it re-reviewed, and you're more than capable of casting a reopen vote (it has its own queue!)

Comment: RE: Fourth Comment: We can't control who uses their close votes, and technically speaking we can't *invalidate* close votes so there's no way to directly *enforce* what you're asking about.  Additionally, gold-badgers for the tags on the post are able to single close-vote just like mods can.  There's no way to filter/control that.  While I agree in principle, enforcement is a different issue.

Comment: RE: Fifth Comment: to be honest, go looking in the history of *answered but not accepted* questions where OP just disappears.  That's not specific to 'close votes' reasons.  However, **none of the mentioned behaviors is harassment** and classifying them as harassment is not your job AND is spreading misinformation about what is actually going on.